# Existe alguma maneira de desabilitar uma view sem deixa-la cinza?

Tags: android

Eu gostaria de padronizar as views, algumas telas para visualizar e editar e outras só para visualizar. Em modo de visualização eu deixo as views desabilitadas.

Estou tentando manter a aparência semelhante, usando o seguinte código:

```
private void enableControls(boolean enable, ViewGroup vg){
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
        child.setEnabled(enable);
        if(enable)
            child.setAlpha(1);
        else
            child.setAlpha(.9f);

        if (child instanceof ViewGroup){
            enableControls(enable, (ViewGroup) child);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `setFocusable(false)`

Comment: Quase! Mas tem o toggle-button que continua funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
Crie um custom xml para essa view e lá altere a cor de quando ela estiver desabilitada e depois chame no `background="@drawable/seu_xml`

**Crie um xml na pasta drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disable" />
    <item android:color="@color/enable"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Interessante, mas eu teria que fazer isso para dezenas de views ! E cada uma com um tipo diferente, por isso estou tentando fazer com código.

Comment: @RodrigoSantiago tente adicionar assim no seu laço: `child.setBackground(R.drawable.seuDrawable)` onde *seuDrawable* é o nome do xml baseado na resposta.

Comment: não consigo fazer isso

Comment: @RodrigoSantiago pensei em uma maneira melhor de fazer oq você quer, dê um view.setClickable(false); ao invés de desabilitá-lo ou trate com uma boolean no setOnClickListener

Comment: acabei de fazer isso, funcionou !